# What's the meaning of one quotation from Edward Davenant?

Tags: sentence-meaning

He said that he *would have a man knockt in the head that should write anything in Mathematiques that had been written of before*. I think in order to understand this sentence one should have some background knowledge. Can anyone explain it?

Comment: Yes, background knowledge. That's precisely why you should add [more context](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) to your question, please.

Comment: Given that [The Venerable Edward Davenant or D'Avenant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_D%27Avenant) lived from 1596–1679, I can't see how his archaic phrasing is relevant to the needs of people wishing to learn English *today.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because about archaic English

Comment: I read a textbook *Probability and Measure* that begins its preface with this quotation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's a very popular quotation among mathematicians, sort of a professional equivalent of the complaint in Ecclesiastes, *Of making many books there is no end* (12:12).

Comment: @StoneyB: *Very popular?* I searched Google Books for [*in the head that should write anything in*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22in+the+head+that+should+write+anything+in%22) before posting my comment, and it returned just 2 results (3 actually, but two of them were duplicates from Aubrey's C17 *Brief Lives*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're right -- I was misled by seeing half a dozen books quoting it, but they all turn out to be reviews or citations of OP's source!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in case you've never encountered the construction *HAVE Object* + *past participle*, you should know that this is not a perfect but a causative. *Have a man knocked in the head* means *cause [somebody unspecified] to knock a man in the head*. We use the same construction in *I'm having my car fixed*.

Beyond this, your quote doesn't require any background knowledge in the subject, but it does require a little knowledge of 17th-century diction and orthography. Let's put it into modern spelling first:

> ... he would have a man knocked in the head that should write anything in mathematics that had been written of before.

There's no usage here that isn't still acceptable in present-day writing, but it's markedly old-fashioned. Today we would probably

- say *any man* rather than *a man*
- say something like *hit over the head* rather than *knocked in the head*
- use the simple past form *wrote* for *should write*
- say *written about* rather than *written of*

And we would probably move the relative clause immediately after its referent.

So paraphrase:

> ... he would have any man who wrote anything in mathematics that had been written about before hit over the head.

But Aubrey's version seems to me considerably more vigorous.

Comment: Interestingly, I recently watched some [maths lectures from Gresham College](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iz4EHriYz0&list=PLEnAx1NqnytD3uS3PGokKK3IKkcdg5iRI). It seems to me that more than one of the speakers referred to how the Internet is shaking up their world, specifically in terms of it now being much easier to discover that other people have also been working on whatever you're interested in. Apparently the true aficionados don't mind finding that their great new idea has already been discovered, because they've still had the joy of finding it out *for themselves* anyway.

Answer (score 0):

> would have a man knockt in the head that should write anything in Mathematiques that had been written of before.

I've modernized the translation to make it easier to understand.

- "knockt in the head" = beaten.
- "a man ... that should write anything" = a man who writes something
- "that had been written of before" = that has been written before (it's nothing new)

**A**: "I would have those men beaten."
**B**: "Which men are you talking about?"
**A**: "Any man who writes anything in Mathematiques that has already been added!"

In other words, if anyone thinks of writing something in Mathematiques a second time, he will make sure they get a beating for doing so.